# The term 'Get-AzureSubscription' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program

Tags: azure-powershell

I installed Az Module with the following command, but I still get the following error.

```
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope AllUsers
```

```
Get-AzureSubscription: The term 'Get-AzureSubscription' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

[image: Get-AzureSubscription not recognized]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command to get the subscription is `Get-AzSubscription`.

Most Azure commands include `Az`, not `Azure`.

You might need to login first with `Connect-AzAccount`, and logging in through the browser popup.

[Sign in with Azure Powershell - Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-7.1.0)

Answer (score 2):

Get-AzSubscription no longer works. Use Get-AzureRmSubscription to retrieve your Azure Subscription details.

Comment: To turn on AzureRM compatibility mode: Enable-AzureRmAlias. This causes commands like Add-AzureRmAccount and  Get-AzureRmSubscription to exist that work like the old Add-AzureAccount and Get-AzureSubscription